# Create multiple columns with different content

Tags: columns

I would like to create multiple columns on one page, but each column have to have completely new content not related with the other columns. I have tried with
\begin{multicol}{n} but thats not the way how to do it. I also include picture how it should look.
Thx for any suggestions[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add some background information/clarifications to your question. Probably a sketch of the desired output could also help. What exactly should your two columns contain? Text, images,...? Will your whole document consist of the two columns? What happens if the left column on one page is filled? Where does the text continue?

Comment: Ok, I didnt know there is needed so much information about it. Both of them should contain just text, its for physics (count some examples). For every example there should be at least 3 columns, I think its not possible to fill whole page with one example. I also added a sketch. It is supposed to look like counted on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use three side by side minipages as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % This package defines the \lispum command that can be used for dummy text. Do NOT use this package in your actual document!


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  some text in the first column 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  some more text in the second column and an equation
  \begin{equation} 
    F = m \cdot a 
  \end{equation} 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You forgot the \noindent,

Answer (score 1):

You can also use paracol.  (I stole the MWE from Leandris.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only.

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{3}
\sloppy% SOP for narrow columns
  some text in the first column 
\switchcolumn
  some more text in the second column and an equation
  \begin{equation} 
    F = m \cdot a 
  \end{equation} 
\switchcolumn
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```